# CasperJS unable to scrape AJAX webpage

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I am trying to scrape `http://www.snapdeal.com/offers/deal-of-the-day` which loads JSON data using an AJAX call to below page:

```
json_url = http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById?*
```

The code block I am using is below, I get the log message `Waiting for AJAX request:`, but not the `Waiting for AJAX request:`, instead `waitForResource` times out

```
casper.options.onResourceRequested = function (casper, requestData){
    // loop through our AJAX urls
    // create list of AJAX urls to track
    var ajaxUrls = [json_url];

    ajaxUrls.every(function(ajaxUrl){
        // does this request match an AJAX url
        if(requestData.url.indexOf(ajaxUrl) !== -1){
            // it matches, so we'll wait for it to return (with 10s timeout)
            //console.log("Waiting for AJAX request: " + requestData.url);
            // print_object(requestData);
            casper.waitForResource(requestData.url, function(){
                console.log("AJAX request returned: " + requestData.url);
            }, function(){
                console.log("AJAX request didn't return after wait period: " + requestData.url)
            }, 10000);
        }
    });
}
```

To further debug, I logged events and the resource at url `json_url` was successfully received, but not sure why `waitForResource` times out.

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    if (resource.url.indexOf('http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById') != -1){
        casper.echo('resource.received: ' + resource.url);

    }

});
```

Log after run:

```
Waiting for AJAX request: http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById?pogIds=671556289429,649272180,60998,685755068805,677649317861,1239888775,661402031482,636966047361,1775140628,1822452791,439536 ,Range,2042952975,1472100667,899358889,643129681532,668235859588,&lang=en

resource.received: http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById?pogIds=671556289429,649272180,60998,685755068805,677649317861,1239888775,661402031482,636966047361,1775140628,1822452791,439536,Range, 2042952975,1472100667,899358889,643129681532,668235859588,&lang=en

resource.received: http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById?pogIds=671556289429,649272180,60998,685755068805,677649317861,1239888775,661402031482,636966047361,1775140628,1822452791,439536,Range, 2042952975,1472100667,899358889,643129681532,668235859588,&lang=en

AJAX request didn't return after wait period: http://www.snapdeal.com/json/getProductById?pogIds=671556289429,649272180,60998,685755068805,677649317861,1239888775,661402031482,636966047361,17751406 28,1822452791,439536,Range,2042952975,1472100667,899358889,643129681532,668235859588,&lang=en Got page No Offeres Found thestartin: ~/Appli
```

Comment: Have you tried waitForSelector, it is a better to identify some resource on the webpage and waitForSelector on that resource.

Comment: Yes I second that, you must use waitForSelector

Comment: Yes I have tried waitForSelector but still it does not work.

Comment: Ok have tried many solutions and seems difficult to get it work. Seems like a valid problem & question to me.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
casper.waitForSelector()
```

or

```
casper.waitFor(function() {
    // test here something that return true when the page is loaded
})
```